# Java return statement confusion

Tags: java

I just want to ask, what is the meaning to (--a,b)? Can somebody explain to me.
Currently i just want to trace the calculation manually, but i was stuck.

This part of the code:

> else if (a%2 == 0)
>     return (-a) * b  + print_it(--a, b);

Comment: I do hope that's a homework question and not real code.

Comment: I would recommend breaking this out a bit, using braces, temp variables, etc. to make this more readable.  Never been a big fan of making the most obscure, obfuscated code possible.  Just my $0.02.

Comment: Using a variable in two places in the same line where one instance has an increment or decrement operator applied to it is a recipe for disaster and Undefined Behavior. I strongly recommend splitting that up.

Comment: @lc. In Java, the behavior is fully defined, even if a variable is used many times, with increment and decrement operators. It may be a homework question that is intended to make that point, and encourage reading the relevant rules. If not, it should definitely be broken up.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Fair enough and interesting to know.

Comment: What is the `print_it` function?

Answer (score 5):

The expression `--a` is the pre-decrement operator, meaning: decrement the value of `a` *before* using it in the expression. Compare it with the expression `a--`, which uses the current value of `a` in the expression and at the end of the evaluation, decrements it.

Answer (score 2):

The `--` and `++` pre and post operators are an area where Java looks just like C or C++, but has significantly different rules.

Evaluation can never appear to be delayed, and the results are fully defined. The key concept is to separate the side effects of an operator from its value.

The general rules for expression evaluation are in [Chapter 15. Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html) in the Java Language Specification. The specifics for --a are in [15.15.2. Prefix Decrement Operator --](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.2) As a side-effect, it reduces the value of a by 1. The value is the value of a *after* the new value is stored.

The [postfix decrement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.3) has the same side-effect, performed at the same point in expression evaluation, but the value of the postfix decrement expression is the value of the variable *before* the new value is stored.